# how to manage save solution before run in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

in visual studio 2015 all times I run the project the project saved automatically

how to manage to save solution before the run in visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 1):

The option to "Save Changes Before Building" was removed from VS 2012 and later.

This feature only existed in VS2010 and below

PS: [For VS 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/10/31/save-changes-before-building/)

Comment: if it helps, upvote/accept it as an answer so others can refer in future